# Create dynamic list of dates in jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

In javascript I need a plain list of dates like (for a jquery datepicker):

```
["16-5-2013", "24-5-2013", "25-5-2013", "26-5-2013"]
```

Because this list is dynamic I want to use this ajax call:

```
var disabledDays = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',       
    url: "/disabled-days",
    });
```

In Django I wrote this test view which returns the data in json:

```
def disabled_days(request, soort):
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import json
    soort = ["16-5-2013", "24-5-2013", "25-5-2013", "26-5-2013", "27-5-2013"]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(soort), mimetype="application/json")
```

Is json here the way to pass the data? I find the date list in the responsText, but I am unable to access this data.

For example I tried to iter over the items like:

```
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays1.length; i++) {
    item = results[i];
    disabledDays.push(item);
}
```

This results in an empty list.

The responsetext is (encoding is json):

```
["16-5-2013", "24-5-2013", "25-5-2013", "26-5-2013"]
```

When I do a console.log() I see this info:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/disabled-days

200 OK
        39ms    
jquery-1.9.1.js (regel 8526)
Object { readyState=1, getResponseHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), meer...}
```

Below is the solution Anh Tú gave (not working yet):

```
var disabledDays1 =     $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',       
    url: "/disabled-days",
    });

var disabledDays = []

for (i = 0; i < disabledDays1.length; i++) {
    item = results[i];
    if(typeof(responsetext)==string){responsetext= JSON.parse(responsetext);} $.each(responsetext,function(i,item){disabledDays.push(item);});

}
console.log(disabledDays);
```

Comment: Show me your responseText

Comment: Try this:

`if(typeof(responsetext)==string){responsetext= JSON.parse(responsetext);} $.each(responsetext,function(i,item){disabledDays.push(item);})`

Comment: @AnhTú Thanks for the reply! I tried your solution, but I end up with an empty list (no errors in the console).

Comment: did you declare disabledDays like this: `var disabledDays =[]` before loop?

Comment: @AnhTú Yes I did. I will edit my question in a minute and show the entire code.

Comment: You're not using the `$.ajax` call correctly. It returns a `jqXHR object` not the response from the URL. What you need to do is implement the `success` function within `$.ajax`. See this for more infohttp://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're handling the ajax request wrong. Normally you declare a callback function when the request success that and process the data received like this:

```
var disabledDays = []
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',       
    url: "/disabled-days",
    success: function(data){
        // data is the response json
        disabledDays = data
        // do whatever it needs to be done with disabledDays, 
        // it should be the array of dates.
        // the process should be inside this method because of asynchronous
        // javascript method execution
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!